# difference between following def and val partial functions

Tags: scala

Is there a difference between whether I use `def` or `val` while defining a partial function? I thought that probably `def` will be evaluated everytime (like a function call) while `val` will be evaluated only once but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
scala> def add(x:Int)(y:Int) = {println("inadd");x+y}
add: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

//def
scala> def add2ToDef= add(2) _
add2ToDef: Int => Int

//val
scala> val add2ToVal= add(2) _
add2ToVal: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1032/1413020227@512abf25

scala> add2ToDef(3)
inadd
res0: Int = 5

scala> add2ToVal(3)
inadd
res1: Int = 5

scala> add2ToDef(4)
inadd
res2: Int = 6

scala> add2ToVal(5)
inadd
res3: Int = 7
```

Comment: I suspect that lambdas can refer to the outside values and thus need to capture the context ("closure"), while a normal function (`def`) does not do that. Hence a lambda is a special object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the same difference as between `val` and `def` in general:

`def` will produce a new lambda (new object) every time you reference it.

`val` will produce it once (at definition time) and every reference to it refers to the same instance.

In this case, `val` makes more sense so it's not creating a new lambda every time.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that:
`def` will be evaluated every time you reference the function and `val` will be evaluated only once and the same value will be used every time.

It is true with partial functions as well. To see the behavior you can see this example:

```
scala> def add(x:Int)(y:Int) = {println("inadd");x+y}
add: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

scala> def addWithDef = add(2)(3)
addWithDef: Int

scala> addWithDef     // Evaluated
inadd
res0: Int = 5

scala> addWithDef     // Evaluated again as "inadd" is printed again  
inadd
res1: Int = 5

scala> val addWithVal = add(2)(3)    // Evaluated once
inadd
addWithVal: Int = 5

scala> addWithVal     //Same value referenced again(no "inadd" printed)
res2: Int = 5

scala> addWithVal     //Same value referenced again(no "inadd" printed)
res3: Int = 5
```